# PHP unlink image from ajax request is not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have created a script to allow to delete images from its uploaded folder and database. This script processing through `AJAX` request. My problem is, image is deleting from db but NOT in folder.

This is my Coding to delete images from folder -

```
if ($numrows == 1) {
    $stmt->bind_result($image_id, $member_id, $image);

    // define constant for upload folder
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', "images/slider/"); 

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        //echo UPLOAD_DIR."$member_id/$image";
        $imagePath = UPLOAD_DIR."$member_id/$image";
        echo $imagePath;

        if(file_exists($imagePath)) {
            unlink($imagePath); 
        } elseif(is_dir($image)) {
            rmdir($image); 
        }
    }               

    // Make the delete query:
    $q = 'DELETE FROM image_info WHERE image_id= ? LIMIT 1'; 
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $imageId);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {
        echo $successAlert;
    }   

    $stmt->close();
    unset($stmt);
}
```

When I echoing the `$imagePath` I found path is correct - `images/slider/18/18_user_banner_1.jpg`

I am trying hard for hours to figure this out. But Still I couldn't have any luck. 
Hope somebody may help me regarding this. 
Thank you.

Comment: What does `var_dump(file_exists($imagePath))` show?

Comment: BTW, you should do the `is_dir()` test first, because `file_exists` will be true if it's a file or a directory.

Comment: probably a permission problem

Comment: @Barmar, var_dump is - `boolean false`

Comment: is your UPLOAD_DIR path correct ??  use same path which you use while upload file

Comment: Then your path is not correct. Maybe you should use an absolute path.

Comment: @Barmar, in other script I use this same path and its working. But this script processing by `AJAX`

Comment: Is the other script in the same folder as this one? Relative paths are relative to the folder containing the script.

Comment: yes.. in the same folder as this one and using relative path

Comment: @Barmar, When I using absolute path its going to this error - `An error occurred in script 'C:\wamp\www\_tutor-backend-develop\includes\process_delete_slideshow-image.php' on line 43: unlink() [function.unlink]: http does not allow unlinking`

Comment: Sounds like you gave an incorrect path. The error implies that the path begins with `http:`, but you should be giving a local pathname, not a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try insted of `define('UPLOAD_DIR', "images/slider/");` give from your DOCUMENT_ROOT path.

ex :

`define('UPLOAD_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/slider/");`